# Increase size of Mountpoint_TempDB?

Tags: sql-server

We are getting errors related to the TempDB max size:

```
Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140747710922752' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
```

I emptied the tempdb folder and tried to run a large query and it quickly filled again. So I tried to increse TempDB's size but this caused an error.

```
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE (
NAME = N'tempdev',
SIZE = 8388608KB ); --8GB
```

`MODIFY FILE encountered operating system error 112(There is not enough space on the disk.) while attempting to expand the physical file 'D:\TempDB\tempdb.mdf'`.

It seems the folder D:\TempDB has a maximum capacity of 1GB. I'm wondering how to change this so we can get back online.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems the folder D:\TempDB has a maximum capacity of 1GB. I'm wondering how to change this so we can get back online.

Is there some Windows quota set on that folder/drive or is the mount point physically out of space? Either way, that's something you'll need to fix in Windows or whoever setup the mountpoint for your D:\TempDB.

If you have usable (GB, performance and permissions) space elsewhere, you can add more tempdb files there temporarily to get back online. Just add a new data file to tempdb in the new, temporary location.

To avoid these issues moving forward, check out the links below:

Optimizing tempdb Performance: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527(v=sql.105).aspx

Troubleshooting Insufficient Disk Space in tempdb: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029(v=sql.105).aspx

Almost everything you'll ever want to know about TempDB: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/tempdb/